# Calculating covariance in Matlab for large dataset and different mean

Tags: matlab, classification, covariance

So I'm trying to implement an EM-Algorithm to train a Gaussian Class Conditional model for classifying data. I'm stuck in the M-step at the moment because I can't figure out how to calculate the covariance matrix.

The problem is I have a big data set and using a for loop to go through each point would be way to slow. I also can't use the covariance function cov(), because I need to use a mean which I calculated using this formula(mu symbol one)

[image: M-step]

Is there a way to adjust cov() to use the mean I want? Or is there another way I could do this without for loops?

Edit: Forgot to explain what the data matrix is like. Its an nx3 where each row is a data point.

It technically needs to work for the general case nxm but n is usually really big(1000 or more) while m is relatively small.

Comment: Could you edit the post to include the working (although slow) version with the loop? That would provide a good starting point for finding performance optimizations.

Comment: @mikkola Sorry but I don't have that code. I was told explicitly that I won't be able to for loop through the data as it would take too long. What I'm looking for is an alternative to for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your covariance matrix manually. Let `data` be the matrix containing all your variables (for example, `[x y]`) and `mu` your custom mean, proceed as follows:

```
n = size(data,1);
data_dem = data - (ones(n,1) * mu);
cov_mat = (data_dem.' * data_dem) ./ (n - 1);
```

Notice that I used the [Bessel's Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) (`n-1` instead of `n`) because the Matlab `cov` function uses it, unless you specify the third argument as `1`:

```
 cov_mat = cov(x,y,1);
```

> C = cov(___,w) specifies the normalization weight for any of the
>   previous syntaxes. When w = 0 (default), C is normalized by the number
>   of observations-1. When w = 1, it is normalized by the number of
>   observations.

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to explain what the sizes of the data set were. I edited the original post, but it's an nx3 matrix where each row is a data point. Does this method work for such a data matrix? From what I understand of covariance(which isn't a lot as it confuses me sometimes) this method shouldn't work, though I could be wrong.